# Hide all instances of element except one currently being written / displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this notification system that works with the following jQuery / javascript and displays a notification when called.

What I am having some trouble doing and what I am trying to do is once a new notification is create to hide and remove / destroy any existing notifications.

I've tried something like this: `$('.notification').not(this).hide().remove();`, but that didn't work.

Here is the jQuery behind the notifications:

```
;(function($) {
$.notificationOptions = {
    className: '',
    click: function() {},
    content: '',
    duration: 5000,
    fadeIn: 400,
    fadeOut: 600,
    limit: false,
    queue: false,
    slideUp: 200,
    horizontal: 'right',
    vertical: 'top',
    afterShow: function(){},
    afterClose: function(){}
};

var Notification = function(board, options) {
    var that = this;
    // build notification template
    var htmlElement = $([
        '<div class="notification ' + options.className + '" style="display:none">',
            '<div class="close"></div>',
            options.content,
        '</div>'
    ].join(''));
    // getter for template
    this.getHtmlElement = function() {
        return htmlElement;
    };
    // custom hide
    this.hide = function() {
        htmlElement.addClass('hiding');
        htmlElement.animate({ opacity: .01 }, options.fadeOut, function() {
            var queued = queue.shift();
            if (queued) {
                $.createNotification(queued);
            }
        });
        htmlElement.slideUp(options.slideUp, function() {
            $(this).remove();
    options.afterClose();
        });
    };
    // show in board
    this.show = function() {
        // append to board and show
        htmlElement[options.vertical == 'top' ? 'appendTo' : 'prependTo'](board);
        htmlElement.fadeIn(options.fadeIn, options.afterShow());
        //$('.notification').css('marginLeft', -$('.notification').outerWidth()/2);
        $('.notification-board.center').css('marginLeft', -($('.notification-board.center').width()/2));
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            $('.notification-board.center').css('marginLeft', -($('.notification-board.center').width()/2));
        });
    };
    // set custom click callback
    htmlElement.on('click', function() {
        options.click.apply(that);
    });
    // helper classes to avoid hide when hover
    htmlElement.on('mouseenter', function() {
        htmlElement.addClass('hover');
        if (htmlElement.hasClass('hiding')) {
            // recover
            htmlElement.stop(true);
            // reset slideUp, could not find a better way to achieve this
            htmlElement.attr('style', 'opacity: ' + htmlElement.css('opacity'));
            htmlElement.animate({ opacity: 1 }, options.fadeIn);
            htmlElement.removeClass('hiding');
            htmlElement.addClass('pending');
        }
    });
    htmlElement.on('mouseleave', function() {
        if (htmlElement.hasClass('pending')) {
            // hide was pending
            that.hide();
        }
        htmlElement.removeClass('hover');
    });
    // close button bind
    htmlElement.children('.close').on('click', function() {
        that.hide();
    });
    if (options.duration) {
        // hide timer
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (htmlElement.hasClass('hover')) {
                // hovering, do not hide now
                htmlElement.addClass('pending');
            } else {
                that.hide();
            }
        }, options.duration);
    }
    return this;
};

var queue = [];

$.createNotification = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({}, $.notificationOptions, options || {});
    // get notification container (aka board)
    var board = $('.notification-board.' + options.horizontal + '.' + options.vertical);
    if (!board.length) {
        board = $('<div class="notification-board ' + options.horizontal + ' ' + options.vertical + '" />');
        board.appendTo('body');
    }
    if (options.limit && board.children('.notification:not(.hiding)').length >= options.limit) {
        // limit reached
        if (options.queue) {
            queue.push(options);
        }
        return;
    }
    // create new notification and show
    var notification = new Notification(board, options)
    notification.show(board);
    return notification;
};

})(jQuery);
```

and here is how the notifications are called / created:

```
$.createNotification({
  horizontal:'center',
  vertical:'top',
  content:'No more cards at this time.',
  duration:6000,
  click:function(){
    this.hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
$('.notification').not(this).hide().remove();
```

will work just fine to remove all .notification DOM elements currently in the DOM except the current one IF `this` is the current notification DOM element.  If that code isn't working, then it's likely because `this` isn't the desired notification DOM element that you want to keep.  If `this` is an instance of your Notification class, then that's the wrong type of object.  For that above code to work, `this` has to be the notification DOM object.

If you want to just remove all old notification DOM elements BEFORE you insert your new one, then you can just do this before your new one is in the DOM:

```
$('.notification').remove();
```

That will clear out the old ones before you insert your new one.

Since you don't have this line of code in your currently posted code, I can't tell where you were trying to use it so can't advise further on what might be wrong.  Please describe further where in your code you were trying to use this.

Comment: I am trying to remove all old notifications right before the new one is created.